# How to store data sent from view to controller in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller

I have a big string data send from view to controller. The string may exceed 65535 characters. I've tried to store it in session flash data.

This is my method in controller to store the data

```
public function get_dt_pemenuhan_d2(){
   $this->load->library('session');

   $list = $this->input->post('no_pnh'); //a huge list of item

   $this->session->set_flashdata('sess_no_pnh',$list);
}
```

and this is my method to retrieve the data from the session flashdata

```
public function pembebanan2(){
    $this->load->library('session');

    $get_no_pnh = $this->session->flashdata('sess_no_pnh');
    $data       = array('no_pnh' => $get_no_pnh);

    $this->load->view('memo_pembebanan2',$data); //sending the data to a view
}
```

Everything is fine for a small data (less than 500 chars). But if I store a huge data, nothing is sent to the view. I've used alert to make sure all the data completely sent to the controller and it's all good. So, what's wrong in the code?

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you

**Edit :**
this is the view and how i post the data to controller and later view it in a pop up view

```
$("#btn_memo").on('click',function(e){
   var arr_pnh = [];
   $('#tbl_content tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){ 
      var x = $(this).text().split('||');
      arr_pnh.push(x[1]);
   });

   var no_pnh = arr_pnh;

   $.post('<?php echo site_url('con_atk/get_dt_pemenuhan_d2'); ?>',{no_pnh:no_pnh},function(){

       popUp = new Boxy("<iframe src='<?php echo site_url('con_atk/pembebanan2') ?>' width='640px' height='480px' frameborder='0'></iframe>" , {title: "<strong>Memo Pembebanan</strong>" , modal: true});
   });
});
```

And this is the view:

```
<div id="div_tbl_body">
            <table id="tbl_content" width="100%" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:4%;  text-align:right">No</th>
                    <th style="width:32%; text-align:center">Names</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            //"<tr><td>"+ no++ +"</td>";<!-- This is generated by AJAX-->
            //    "<td align='center'>"+ id +"<font size='1px' color='#FFFFFF'>||"+no_pnh+"</font></td></tr>";<!-- This is generated by AJAX-->
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

My question is why I could not store huge sata in the session? are there any option to store huge data in controller and can be accessed by the method except using session?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** After researching, I have found a suggestion and most likely may work.

I saw that sessions have a limited size, and also, even cookies.

The best way for you to do it is to get the data, store it in a database, get in from your model into your controller, and then pass it to the popup.

Your next option would be storing it into a .txt file then loading it from there.

**EDIT:** Here is something you can do.

Post the data do a controller, instead of doing this

```
public function get_dt_pemenuhan_d2(){
$this->load->library('session');

$list = $this->input->post('no_pnh'); //a huge list of item

$this->session->set_flashdata('sess_no_pnh',$list); 
}
```

Do this

```
public function get_dt_pemenuha_d2()
{
    $this->load->model('your_model');
    $list = $this-input->post('no_pnh');
    $this->your_model->insert_into_table($list);
 }
```

This would be your model function

```
public function insert_into_table($list)
{
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$list);
}
```

then if you want to access it just do this

```
public function pembebanan2()
{
    $this->load->model('your_model');
    $data['list'] = $this->your_model->get_list();
    $this->load->view('memo_pembebanan2',$data);
}
```

this is your get_list function

```
public function get_list()
{
  $this->db->get('yourtable');
}
```

you can just delete the inside of the table if you want after it's done or put an ID to be able to use a where clause if you want to keep others lists.

No need to make it into a global variable, just load your model and get your list

now in your view you just need to echo that $list

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

The data is not from database. It's from a table in a view. It's just a huge list of names. I can't use the function you suggested because i use some kind of pop up plugin that need to use session.

Comment: Oh I'm sory. You're trying to display the characters in the popup boxy am i correct?

Comment: yeah. actually it's working fine. but for roughly 500 chars or around 75 names in the list. I may need more than this. Over 1000 names may needed.

Comment: Can you edit your question and also post the view? I'll try to see it

Comment: it's a usual html table generated by ajax. See my edit

Comment: I have edited my answer and gave you my suggestion. Hope this helps you

Comment: can i make it to a global variable in controller? but still using the form

Comment: Editted my answer again, hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'd really like not to use the database method (loading over 1000 result sure takes time). But i'll use it if i have no other option :)

Comment: @LorenzoMagno When you set_flashdata it only works when you use redirect().

Comment: @Vahn you could opt for the .txt one, may be lighter and if you could accept my answe :)

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yea my answer earlier just posted and didn't use flash data. Thanks though

Comment: my friend suggested using ci_sessions, but it also has to deal with database which i'd really avoid.

Comment: @Lorenzo Magno I'll still waiting for the non database solution. I'll accept your answer if there are no option except using database.

Comment: Okay no problem, but If I think of another solution, I'll edit my post. Goodluck and have fun coding mate! @Vahn

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just try to compress data using `gzencode`

sth like that:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('sess_no_pnh', gzencode($list));
```

or just store it in a temp file, and keep reference into session:

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $list);
fclose($handle);
$this->session->set_flashdata('sess_no_pnh', $tmpfname);
```

and then just read it in popup:

```
$get_no_pnh = $this->session->flashdata('sess_no_pnh');
$data       = array('no_pnh' => file_get_contents($get_no_pnh));
unlink($get_no_pnh);
```